# IF contains special chars?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Quick question, is there anyway I can modify this statement to  include all special characters, i.e. !?&^%$£ etc

```
If tb.Text.Contains("!") Then
        Score += 25
    End If
```

I've tried

```
If tb.Text.Contains("!"|"?"|"*") Then
        Score += 25
    End If
```

and

```
If tb.Text.Contains("!","?","*") Then
        Score += 25
    End If
```

If there isn't a way I could just write them out individually but i'd prefer to have them within a few lines if possible, thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Regular Expressions](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet).  You can--carefully, since the "special characters" also often do things in the regular expression, which you need to escape, and I may not have caught them all--have something like

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(tb.Text,"(!|\?|&|^|%|\$|£)")
```

(The pipes, in this case, show alternate things to match.  Since you're looking for any of the characters, it's fairly easy *except* for the aforementioned caveat.)

And then check the value of `m.Success`.